# Displaying a lake on a DEM

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, dem, arcgis-10.4

I am using ArcGIS 10.4.1

I have a 50% shaded dem layer on top of a hillshade layer. The colors look nice, but I have a lake I want to display as blue in the dem, which I don't know how to color properly. 
[image]

I guess if the lake would have been at sea level this would have been a simple task, but when the lake is at 50 meter height, I don't know what to do.

Comment: How about extracting the lake from the DEM and have it as it's own stand alone layer and you can color as needed?

Comment: https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/10/27/using-curvature-rasters-to-enhance-terrain-representation/ gives an example on how I want it. I don't follow the last step where he "simply used a color ramp of blues" Has the raster with the lake been extracted here?

Comment: Can you add additional screen shots of the each layer separately? Also, would you be able to share the dataset so I can test out?

Comment: It looks like you already have a polygon that represents the lake boundary.  Fill the polygon with a blue color using the layer properties-symbology.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.